# FosUser, Create a user manually

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

For a special case in my application, i need to register a user manually from an ajax request.

So, first i send with ajax all my datas : `firstname, lastname, mail, password etc...` to my controller.

For now, after that, i just do in my controller :

```
    $firstname = $request->get('firstname');
    $lastname = $request->get('lastname');
    $mail = $request->get('mail');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setUsername($firstname.$lastname);
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
    $user->setEmail($mail);
    $user->setFirstname($firstname);
    $user->setLastname($lastname);

    $userManager->updateUser($user);
```

But my problem, how can i validate the user before `updateUser()` ? I need to check manually if this email/username already exist ?

How can i do that with a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the email arealdy exists with the `findUserByEmail` method just before the `updateUser` :

```
$user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($mail);
```